# TinyMCE bold not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, tinymce-rails

I have used Tinymce editor in my rails app. When I try to make a text bold and save, the text changes are not reflected.

Gemfile

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

congig/tinymce.yml

```
selector: textarea.table-editor
theme: modern
selector: textarea
toolbar: styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | table | alignleft 
         aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor | emoticons
plugins:
      - table 
      - advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor  pagebreak spellchecker
      - searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking 
      - save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor
```

application.js

```
 //= require tinymce
```

something.html.erb

```
 <%= tinymce_assets %>
 <%= tinymce %>
 <%= form.text_area :description, :class => "tinymce", id: :course_description %>
```

show.html.erb

```
 <%= @course.description.html_safe %>
```

Comment: @sawa bold functionality is not working

Answer (score 1):

Normally all these wysiwyg editors format your input in to `html`, `markdown` etc under the hood and saves to the data base.

If we consider html, when you make a text bold, for an example it maybe adding a `<b></b>` tag around your text.

I can see you have the [`code`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/code/) plugin in the list. As per the documentation of the plugin, it should allow you to view the html of your editing changes.

As a test,

- Make a text bold in the editor
- Switch to `Source` view and see if your text is surrounded by bold tags.
- If `yes`, make sure you backend saves the same string in to the database. Make sure you dont have any code that strips out the html tags
- If `no`, then the editor is not converting your changes, you may have to check the editor configs.

Comment: at the backend even after it get saves the text is around <strong> tag but it doesnt show in that way

Comment: @SushmaKv, when you show up the text, use `raw` method to show the html content. otherwise rails by default not showing the html , please note, only works in helpers and views by default -> https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw

Comment: i tried adding raw but its nt working the way it should

Comment: can you update the question with the code where you expect the text to see as bold

Comment: @SushmaKv can you post the actual text that is saved in `course.description` as it appears in the database?